# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null using querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried getElementsByClassName it got the same error, that's strange. In my html I'd change `<p id="trigger-overlay">` to

```
<p class="trigger-overlay">
```

error

```
function toggleOverlay(){alert('fire');};
var triggerBttn = document.querySelector('trigger-overlay');
triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

working

```
function toggleOverlay(){alert('fire');};
var triggerBttn = document. getElementById('trigger-overlay');
triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.trigger-overlay');` - missing class selector(`.`)

Answer (score 3):

Class selector should start with `.` dot: `document.querySelector('.trigger-overlay');`.

**MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors