# addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML like this

```
<p class="trigger-overlay">
```

but got error of addEventListener is not a function

```
function toggleOverlay(){alert('fire');};
var triggerBttn = document. getElementsByClassName('trigger-overlay');
triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

I use id and it's working, but I want to be able to trigger on multiple classes.

```
function toggleOverlay(){alert('fire');};
var triggerBttn = document. getElementById('trigger-overlay');
triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

Comment: Why spaces `document. getEl`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a html collection object which doesn't have the `addEventListener` method

Comment: [Do you have multiple accounts? Or you both are doing the same homework?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33166233/1249581)

Comment: @VisioN paying college is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

The function getElementsByClassName will return you collection of html elements so use indexer to access each element returned.

```
for(i=0; i < triggerBttn.length; i++)
   triggerBttn[i].addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

To do it with jQuery you can do like

```
$('.triggerBttn').click(toggleOverlay);
```

Comment: that's why I want to write jquery

Comment: @MaySun: So do that. There's [plenty of](http://api.jquery.com) information available [telling you how](http://learn.jquery.com/)